# Help identify fantasy novel about a wizard slandered/libeled as Don Quixote

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to find a humorous fantasy novel I once read which I believe was written in the 1980's. It starts out with a wizard running a small magic school, but he ends up leaving (possibly by force) and traveling around on adventures. While he is traveling an unknown writer libels/slanders him as essentially being Don Quixote. He meets up with the writer at the end of the novel, but unfortunately that's all I remember.